# Do coins and dragon coins do anything in the Super Mario World minigame?

Tags: warioware-get-it-together

In the 9-Volt boss minigame *Super Mario World*, there are coins and Dragon Coins scattered throughout each level. In the original Super Mario World, collecting 100 coins total or 5 dragon coins would earn an extra life.

Does collecting coins or dragon coins do anything in the *WarioWare: Get It Together* remake?

[image]